# Drawing all players in real time multiplayer Google Play

Tags: libgdx, google-play-services

I am building a real time multilayer with Libgdx and Google play services BaseGameUtils and at a point where I am able to bring players into the waiting room and start the game but when I tested the game it only shows one player on the screen.

My question is:

is the game room (Google API) responsible for drawing all participants on the game room screen or do I have to implement it somehow in my game screen

Once the minimum required players have entered the room, this is how I start the game screen

```
public void startGame(){
    Log.d(TAG, "startGame()");

    gameActivity.setScreen(new Play(gameActivity));

}
```

Comment: As it is this is a bad question because you are basically asking "how do I make a multiplayer game" to which the answer is "by coding a multiplayer game". Are you having problems with the network communication, the sprite rendering, etc.

Comment: Let me re phrase the question.

Comment: does that makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about networking things. But what i know is, that the connection is extremly limited, so try to send as few data as possible. For a 3D game maybe send a `Vector3 position`, `Vector3 direction`, to draw the player at the right position with the right rotation. For a 2D game use `Vector2` as you don't have the `z-Axis`. Maybe you also need to send an `int class`, which defines which class the player has (Knight, Whizzard...).
So basicly you send only data for the logic, never objects, like models, textures...
The drawing is always performed on the client. The server does only some logic, like validating the positions...

Answer (score 0):

LibGDX is not a part of Android, any Google API calls will not render content in a LibGDX game. Your calls might affect what is displayed in another application that relies on the same service (like the "Play Games" app). If you want to display something in your game you'll have to code that functionality yourself.

Comment: Where can I find some documentation on where to start.

Comment: Look at how your `Play` screen renders something on screen. now do that for all the other players you retrieve by calling the network service. You might need to start with a non-networking game to get the basics down first.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will have to research it more